# restart node.js server from bat file

Tags: node.js, windows, batch-file

I'm trying to restart a node.js server without any thrid party library. The bat file is executed from the node server itself.

Here is the restart.bat file:

```
set processId=%1
taskkill /F /PID %processId%
node app.js
```

Here is the code which is supposed to run the bat file:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('restart.bat ' + process.pid,
    function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log('error: ' + error);
        console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
        console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    }
);
```

With the code above, the process is killed but the server never restart.

Can someone help please ?

PS: my node version is v8.11.4

Comment: Consider `const { exec } = require('child_process')` if you're using a newer Node. ES6 has [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Comment: @tadman I think the batch process dies when the node process dies. that's why the batch never execute `node app.js`. Does the batch process executes over the node process ? If yes how to detach it and let it run as a singleton ?

Comment: Instead of leaning on a batch file, try and perform those two operations entirely within Node using [child process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) control.